# How to suppress displaying specific columns on dynamic tables

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two dynamic tables that I am left joining. I want to suppress displaying specific column from both tables. So far, this is my query:

```
SELECT a.*
    ,b.*
FROM APEXCOUNTYREVIEW_REPORT a
LEFT JOIN TBL_LOW_VOLUME_test b 
    ON a.fips_data_type = b.fips_datatype
```

Both of these are dynamic tables with plenty of columns. I want to suppress columns in the middle of the tables.
For example, `Table1` has columns `C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7,...etc.` I do not want to pull columns `C3, C4 and C5`, but want to display `C1, C2, C6, C7` and so forth. Since both of these are dynamic tables, the number of columns is not known until execution of the query. I'm using SSMS 2008 R2.

Is there a way to do this with SQL query?

Here's the query to build table2, tbl_low_voulume_test:
I'm also trying to add a text to the column name on table2, since they are the same as the column names on table1, that is being created dynamically and I'm getting all kinds of invalid error messages. How can I add the text "Flag" on the dynamic column names?

The query below runs fine.

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(Y INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

DECLARE
@COLS AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@COLNAMES AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Y    AS INT,
@SQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @COLS = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(Y)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RECMONTH AS Y FROM REPORTING.dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME A

WHERE (RECMONTH>= '2005-01')
AND RECMONTH <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), getdate(), 120)
) AS Y
ORDER BY Y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

SET @COLNAMES = STUFF(
(SELECT N',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Y)+',0) AS '+ QUOTENAME(Y) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RECMONTH AS [Y] FROM REPORTING.dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME A

WHERE (RECMONTH>= '2005-01')
AND RECMONTH <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), getdate(), 120)
) AS Y
ORDER BY Y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

IF OBJECT_ID('TBL_LOW_VOLUME_test') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE reporting.dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME_test END 


SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME_test 
FROM (
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS RUN_DATE, FIPS+DATATYPE AS FIPS_DATATYPE,
 FIPS,DATATYPE,' +@COLNAMES + ' 
FROM (SELECT A.[FIPS], A.DATATYPE
      ,RECMONTH
      ,[LV_FLAG]
    FROM dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME A
    where FIPS is not NULL and isnumeric(FIPS) = 1 and len(ltrim(FIPS)) = 5
     and FIPS not in (''-0000'',''00000'',''-0001'')
     and FIPS <= ''56999''

 ) AS D
PIVOT(SUM([LV_FLAG]) FOR RECMONTH IN(' + @COLS + N')) AS P) AS Z';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

Here's a picture of my two tables.
Table1:

col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, etc...
columns 1 thru 5 are static, starting on column c0l6, it becomes dynamic where every beginning of the month it adds a new month.

Table2:
cola, colb, colc, cold, cole, colf, etc...
columns a and b are both static, the rest are dynamic where every beginning of the month it adds a new month.

This should be the final results I want to display.

col1, col2, col6, etc...(all the dynamic columns on table1), cola, colc, cole, etc...(all the dynamic columns on table2)

So I want to pick and choose which columns I need from each table.

Here's the query after I did print @sql:
For this table, I do not want to display Run_Date and FIPS_DATATYPE, just all the date columns.

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME_test 
FROM (
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS RUN_DATE, FIPS+DATATYPE AS FIPS_DATATYPE,
 ISNULL([2005-01],0) AS [2005-01],ISNULL([2005-02],0) AS [2005-02],ISNULL([2005-03],0) AS [2005-03],ISNULL([2005-04],0) AS [2005-04],
ISNULL([2005-05],0) AS [2005-05],ISNULL([2005-06],0) AS [2005-06],ISNULL([2005-07],0) AS [2005-07],ISNULL([2005-08],0) AS [2005-08],
ISNULL([2005-09],0) AS [2005-09],ISNULL([2005-10],0) AS [2005-10],ISNULL([2005-11],0) AS [2005-11],ISNULL([2005-12],0) AS [2005-12],
ISNULL([2006-01],0) AS [2006-01],ISNULL([2006-02],0) AS [2006-02],ISNULL([2006-03],0) AS [2006-03],ISNULL([2006-04],0) AS [2006-04],
ISNULL([2006-05],0) AS [2006-05],ISNULL([2006-06],0) AS [2006-06],ISNULL([2006-07],0) AS [2006-07],ISNULL([2006-08],0) AS [2006-08],
ISNULL([2006-09],0) AS [2006-09],ISNULL([2006-10],0) AS [2006-10],ISNULL([2006-11],0) AS [2006-11],ISNULL([2006-12],0) AS [2006-12],
ISNULL([2007-01],0) AS [2007-01],ISNULL([2007-02],0) AS [2007-02],ISNULL([2007-03],0) AS [2007-03],ISNULL([2007-04],0) AS [2007-04],
ISNULL([2007-05],0) AS [2007-05],ISNULL([2007-06],0) AS [2007-06],ISNULL([2007-07],0) AS [2007-07],ISNULL([2007-08],0) AS [2007-08],
ISNULL([2007-09],0) AS [2007-09],ISNULL([2007-10],0) AS [2007-10],ISNULL([2007-11],0) AS [2007-11],ISNULL([2007-12],0) AS [2007-12],
ISNULL([2008-01],0) AS [2008-01],ISNULL([2008-02],0) AS [2008-02],ISNULL([2008-03],0) AS [2008-03],ISNULL([2008-04],0) AS [2008-04],
ISNULL([2008-05],0) AS [2008-05],ISNULL([2008-06],0) AS [2008-06],ISNULL([2008-07],0) AS [2008-07],ISNULL([2008-08],0) AS [2008-08],
ISNULL([2008-09],0) AS [2008-09],ISNULL([2008-10],0) AS [2008-10],ISNULL([2008-11],0) AS [2008-11],ISNULL([2008-12],0) AS [2008-12],
ISNULL([2009-01],0) AS [2009-01],ISNULL([2009-02],0) AS [2009-02],ISNULL([2009-03],0) AS [2009-03],ISNULL([2009-04],0) AS [2009-04],
ISNULL([2009-05],0) AS [2009-05],ISNULL([2009-06],0) AS [2009-06],ISNULL([2009-07],0) AS [2009-07],ISNULL([2009-08],0) AS [2009-08],
ISNULL([2009-09],0) AS [2009-09],ISNULL([2009-10],0) AS [2009-10],ISNULL([2009-11],0) AS [2009-11],ISNULL([2009-12],0) AS [2009-12],
ISNULL([2010-01],0) AS [2010-01],ISNULL([2010-02],0) AS [2010-02],ISNULL([2010-03],0) AS [2010-03],ISNULL([2010-04],0) AS [2010-04],
ISNULL([2010-05],0) AS [2010-05],ISNULL([2010-06],0) AS [2010-06],ISNULL([2010-07],0) AS [2010-07],ISNULL([2010-08],0) AS [2010-08],
ISNULL([2010-09],0) AS [2010-09],ISNULL([2010-10],0) AS [2010-10],ISNULL([2010-11],0) AS [2010-11],ISNULL([2010-12],0) AS [2010-12],
ISNULL([2011-01],0) AS [2011-01],ISNULL([2011-02],0) AS [2011-02],ISNULL([2011-03],0) AS [2011-03],ISNULL([2011-04],0) AS [2011-04],
ISNULL([2011-05],0) AS [2011-05],ISNULL([2011-06],0) AS [2011-06],ISNULL([2011-07],0) AS [2011-07],ISNULL([2011-08],0) AS [2011-08],
ISNULL([2011-09],0) AS [2011-09],ISNULL([2011-10],0) AS [2011-10],ISNULL([2011-11],0) AS [2011-11],ISNULL([2011-12],0) AS [2011-12],
ISNULL([2012-01],0) AS [2012-01],ISNULL([2012-02],0) AS [2012-02],ISNULL([2012-03],0) AS [2012-03],ISNULL([2012-04],0) AS [2012-04],
ISNULL([2012-05],0) AS [2012-05],ISNULL([2012-06],0) AS [2012-06],ISNULL([2012-07],0) AS [2012-07],ISNULL([2012-08],0) AS [2012-08],
ISNULL([2012-09],0) AS [2012-09],ISNULL([2012-10],0) AS [2012-10],ISNULL([2012-11],0) AS [2012-11],ISNULL([2012-12],0) AS [2012-12],
ISNULL([2013-01],0) AS [2013-01],ISNULL([2013-02],0) AS [2013-02],ISNULL([2013-03],0) AS [2013-03],ISNULL([2013-04],0) AS [2013-04],
ISNULL([2013-05],0) AS [2013-05],ISNULL([2013-06],0) AS [2013-06],ISNULL([2013-07],0) AS [2013-07],ISNULL([2013-08],0) AS [2013-08],
ISNULL([2013-09],0) AS [2013-09],ISNULL([2013-10],0) AS [2013-10],ISNULL([2013-11],0) AS [2013-11],ISNULL([2013-12],0) AS [2013-12],
ISNULL([2014-01],0) AS [2014-01],ISNULL([2014-02],0) AS [2014-02],ISNULL([2014-03],0) AS [2014-03],ISNULL([2014-04],0) AS [2014-04],
ISNULL([2014-05],0) AS [2014-05],ISNULL([2014-06],0) AS [2014-06],ISNULL([2014-07],0) AS [2014-07],ISNULL([2014-08],0) AS [2014-08],
ISNULL([2014-09],0) AS [2014-09],ISNULL([2014-10],0) AS [2014-10],ISNULL([2014-11],0) AS [2014-11],ISNULL([2014-12],0) AS [2014-12],
ISNULL([2015-01],0) AS [2015-01],ISNULL([2015-02],0) AS [2015-02]
```

Comment: Include your business rules in the logic that builds the dynamic string.

Comment: Hi Tab, I edited the original entry adding the query that creates table2. Table1 for now is still static in my database, but it will be dynamic for this query that I'm doing.

Comment: Could you PRINT @SQL right before you execute it, and add the SQL string to your post?   I can't picture how the columns you want to delete are getting into the string in the first place.

Comment: I added the query after I did a Print @sql.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add the text "Flag" on the dynamic column names?

Looks to me like you want to replace

```
QUOTENAME(Y)
```

with

```
QUOTENAME(Y+'Flag')
```

Everywhere it occurs in both the `SET @COLS` and `SET @COLNAMES` statements.

EDIT:  To filter out columns, looking at your final select, you're doing SELECT * FROM (a derived table that specifies static columns + COLNAMES).

So to filter out columns, filter them out of the derived table.   They have to be either the static columns RUN_DATE, FIPS_DATATYPE, FIPS, DATATYPE, or one of the columns in COLNAMES, which you can filter out with a REPLACE function.

Or if I am not understanding the problem, please post sample output of your current query and which rows you want to filter out.

2ND EDIT:   To take Run_Date and FIPS_DATATYPE out of your results, simply take them out of the middle-level select:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME_test 
FROM (
SELECT  ' +@COLNAMES + ' 
FROM ...
```

Comment: I added the code to all occurrences of QuoteName(Y) but I'm getting this error on this part of the code: SELECT N',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Y+'Flag'),0) AS '+ QUOTENAME(Y+'Flag')  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RECMONTH AS [Y]  FROM REPORTING.dbo.TBL_LOW_VOLUME A

Comment: Here's the error message I get on the 2nd quotename(Y)         Incorrect syntax near '+ QUOTENAME(Y+'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 45
Incorrect syntax near ''.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ';

Comment: Never mind, I got the syntax error corrected. Now back to my original question on suppressing of columns issue on dynamic tables....

Comment: Do a REPLACE() on COLS and COLNAMES to take out the columns you want to suppress.   Or use a WHERE clause in the SET statements to prevent them from being added to the string in the first place.

Comment: The columns I want suppressed is not the part where it is dynamic. Part of the table are static columns and those are the ones I want to suppress, but I want all the dynamic columns displayed. My query has the .* to display all the dynamic columns but it also displays the rest of the table columns. I cannot use the where clause because I need all the dynamic columns.

Comment: I edited my original posting with an explanation of what my results should be.

Comment: When creating table2, I need to have the RUN_DATE and FIPS_DATATYPE so I can use them to join to another table. When I do the pivot on this table, these two columns will identify the rest of the date columns. When I use this table later to create the final results I need, I left join it to another table that needs the FIPS_DATATYPE column, otherwise I will not be able to pull the rest of the data from table1.

Comment: Sounds like you're not showing the entire code.   Anyway, what you can do then, is use the existing query to populate a temp table (or table variable).   Use it to do the joins and whatever else you need it for, and then in the final select, only select the columns you want.